# Lambda function to subtract x and the prior element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains some timestamps and I need to calculate the difference between each timestamp, for each ID. My dataframe is the following:

```
ID    Value   Date       Date_diff_cumsum   visVal  Weight   TempVal
 1    0.000 2017-02-13 20:54:00      0.0    0.000    75.0       NaN
 1   29.598 2017-02-13 21:02:00      8.0   29.598    75.0  4.933000
 1  273.000 2017-02-13 22:33:00      99.0  273.000   75.0  3.676768
 1  153.000 2017-02-13 23:24:00      150.0  153.000  75.0  1.360000
 1  136.902 2017-02-14 00:01:00      187.0  136.902  75.0  0.976128
```

Now, I need to calculate Date_diff_cumsum as the difference between each timestamp, not from the first timestamp. My code is the following:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['Date'])
df['Date_diff_cumsum'] = df.groupby('ID').Date.diff().dt.seconds / 60.0
df['Date_diff_cumsum'] = df.groupby('ID').Date_diff_cumsum.cumsum().fillna(0)
df['Value'] = df['Value'].apply(lambda x: x*1000)
df['visVal'] = df.groupby('ID')['Value'].transform(lambda x:(x-x.iloc[0]*100))
df['Weight'] = df['ID'].map(dfWeight.set_index('ID')['Value']).fillna(0)
df['TempVal'] = (df['Value']/(df['Weight'] * df['Date_diff_cumsum'])*100).fillna(0)
```

How do I modify the lambda func to calculate the Date_diff_cumsum between a timestamp the prior one?

Also, at the end of the function, I repeat the same operations on other dataframes and need to sum all the TempVal for each dataframe and each timestamp this is the code:

```
frame = [df, df1, df2]


final = pd.concat(frame)
final['FinalVal'] = final.groupby('ID')['TempVal'].cumsum()
```

IS the last part correct for the sum of each TempVal in each df at the same timestamp?
Thank you very much

EDIT: expected output:

```
ID    Value   Date       Date_diff_cumsum   visVal  Weight   TempVal
1    0.000 2017-02-13 20:54:00      0.0    0.000    75.0       0.0
1   29.598 2017-02-13 21:02:00      8.0    29.598   75.0       4.31
1  273.000 2017-02-13 22:33:00      91.0   273.000  75.0       4
1  153.000 2017-02-13 23:24:00      59.0   153.000  75.0       3.45
1  136.902 2017-02-14 00:01:00      37.0   136.902  75.0       4.9
```

And in my finalDf, since I don't have nothing because I'm stuck:
from df, df1, df2, sum of all TempVal for each timestamp, something similar to this

```
ID  TempVal1   Date              TempVal2  TempVal3       FinalVal
1   0.000  2017-02-13 20:54:00   0.0       0.000          0.0
1   4.31   2017-02-13 21:02:00   8.0      NaN             12.31
1   4      2017-02-13 22:33:00   91.0     273.000         368
1  3.45    2017-02-13 23:24:00   NaN      153.000         156.45
1  4.9     2017-02-14 00:01:00   37.0     NaN             41.9
```

Where, if I don't have a measurement for that timestamp in one dataframe, in the final dataframe it is considered NaN or 0

Comment: Can you add expected output based on your example data?

Comment: we you can just do: `df['Date_diff_cumsum']=df.groupby('ID')['Date'].diff().dt.total_seconds()//60` , no need of doing it twice

Comment: The rest is ok? Because I'm getting very high values

Comment: ok i thought the question was just for `Date_diff_cumsum`

Comment: I added an example of final dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked with just the 'Diff' column The data I used is just Value & Date

```html
Value  Date
0.000  2017-02-1320:54:00
29.598  2017-02-1321:02:00
273.000 2017-02-1322:33:00
153.000 2017-02-1323:24:00
136.902 2017-02-1400:01:00
```

Then the code below

```
from datetime import timedelta
df['diffT']=((pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S')).diff())//timedelta(minutes=1)
```

The result is as below. Check if this helps

```html
Value  Date                  diffT
0.000  2017-02-1320:54:00  NaN
29.598  2017-02-1321:02:00  8.0
273.000 2017-02-1322:33:00  91.0
153.000 2017-02-1323:24:00  51.0
136.902 2017-02-1400:01:00  37.0
```